# Angular 11 can't achieve to test if an url was called

Tags: angular, testing, angular-test, angular-testing-library

I had a problem with **angular testing**. I want to detect when an **url change** on a button click. I followed a lot of similar issues on stack but can't achieve to my goal since 1 one week :/

## Explanation

Here is my HTML template:

```html
<a id="signInButton" [routerLink]="['/my/route/call']">Sign in</a>
```

Here is my test:

```js
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture< MyComponent >;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  // Creating mocked router here
  const router = {
    navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate'),
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        DatabaseModule.forRoot(),
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
      ],
      providers: [
       MyComponentService,
        { provide: Router, useValue: router },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  beforeEach(() => (httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController)));

  afterEach(() => {
    router.navigate.calls.reset();
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  fit('should redirect on sign in click', async () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const signInButton = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector(
      '#signInButton'
    );
    signInButton.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
    
    // impossible to pass this step :/
    expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/my/route/call']);
  });
});
```

When I run the test, I have **two errors**:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'detectChanges' of undefined
```

## Researchs

- After some research on stack, I managed to remove `RouterTestingModule` from imports and now I'm getting:

```
Expected spy navigate to have been called with:
  [ [ '/my/route/call' ] ]
but it was never called.
```

- Another searches on stack :p, I managed to remove `{ provide: Router, useValue: router }` but keep `RouterTestingModule` and I'm getting:

```
Expected spy navigate to have been called with:
  [ [ '/my/route/call' ] ]
but it was never called.
```

[image: console error]

NOTE: I noticed that all  link are not rendered when I'm removing `RouterTestingModule`, so I think the solution is to achieve to combine `RouterTestingModule` and `{ provide: Router, useValue: router },`?

- When I use a `(click)` instead of `routerLink` it's working well, why ?

```html
<a id="signInButton" (click)="openNewPage()">Sign in</a>
```

```js
openNewPage() {
  this.router.navigate(['/my/route/call']);
}
```

Any help would be amazing :)
Thanks in advance !